# httpclient does not work in asynctask

Tags: android, httpclient, session-cookies

i am using `httpclient` in `asynctask doInBackground` for get my `php-session` value

this is my `Java` codes:

```
package com.example.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String aktuell_date_u,set_check;
    public static DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_main);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("bitte warten...");
        pd.show();

        new get_sessions();

    }
    private class get_sessions extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            HttpGet post = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/getsessions.php");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                return new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
            aktuell_date_u = result.optString("aktuell_date_u").toString();
            set_check = result.optString("set_check").toString();
            pd.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my `php` codes:

```
<?php

session_start();

header('content-type: aplication/json; charset=utf-8');

setcookie("cookie_test", date('U'));

$aktuell_date_u=date('U');
$_SESSION['set_check']=md5($aktuell_date_u);

echo '{"aktuell_date_u":"'.$aktuell_date_u.'","set_check":"'.$_SESSION['set_check'].'"}';

?>
```

the `PregressDialog` loads and loads ...

what i'm doing wrong, because my `httpclient codes` work out of `doInBackground`

Special thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the `AsyncTask`'s `execute()` method, so the AsyncTask never runs. Instead of

```
new get_sessions();
```

You need to call:

```
new get_sessions().execute(null);
```

As you're not using the arguments passed to `doInBackground()`, I'm not sure why you've defined them as `String`.

You should probably also look at some basic training on Java coding conventions and follow them - things like making Class names begin with an uppercase letter and camel casing them rather than using underscores. Following conventions makes your code easier for other people to read.